# Does the mass moment of inertia stay the same for a particular spinning object?

Tags: angular-momentum, moment-of-inertia, angular-velocity

A solid disk of mass m and radius r spinning about it's central axis would have a mass moment of inertia, I = (1/2)mr^2.
But according to the conservation law of angular momentum, the initial angular momentum L1 and the final angular momentum L2 would be the same.
If so, then,
L1 = L2
or, I1W1 = I2W2
or, I1/I2 = W2/W1 (W1 initial angular velocity, W2 final angular  velocity)
and here you see more than one mass moment of inertia for a particular body saying inertia gets bigger if the spinning is slow and smaller for fast spin.

What would be equal to I = (1/2)mr^2? Is it I1 or I2?

Comment: Inertia here remains constant, you have applied conservation of angular momentum wrongly here

Comment: Why would the angular speed change? is there any force acting or is the shape of the object changing?

Comment: Hello! It is [preferable](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563/) to use MathJax (LaTeX) to display formulas. You can find a tutorial at [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Please [edit] your question accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: The shape of the object isn't changing. The body itself is able to increase or reduce it's speed. @Wolphramjonny

Comment: It would be helpful if you could tell me where I applied it wrong and also how to apply it the proper way. @Param_1729

Comment: If so, there must be  torque, and angular momentum is not conserved. The moment of inertia will not change.

Comment: Moment of Inertia about an axis $I = \int r^2dm$, only depends on mass distribution and is constant. Now if we want to apply conservation of angular momentum(which can be only applied if external torque is zero) then we get $IW_1 = IW_2$ which implies $W_1=W_2$. Thus from angular momentum conservation we get that $W$ remains constant when net external torque is zero.